# Need to look up values between Excel Worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 excel sheets that look something like this:

Sheet 1 has dates and lots in 2 columns

Date Lot

12/30/04 108

12/05/13 210

10/18/05 175

09/08/05 149

Sheet 2 only has lots, but several of them occur multiple times.

Lot Date

108

108

210

175

149

108

***How do I get excel to automatically populate the dates from Sheet 1?***

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a quick Google search on the Excel VLOOKUP worksheet function.  If you are trying to get the data associated with a lot from Sheet 1 into a cell on Sheet 2, most of the hundreds of sites that will do the trick for you.  VLOOKUP is your best friend in Excel (in my humble opinion).